# How can you assign a variable that is defined inside an if else statement

Tags: java, if-statement

I need to create something that will find the current hour in GMT and convert it into EST.

When I attempt to compile and run the program I receive this error: `currentHourEST cannot be resolved to a variable`. I think that my issue is someplace down in the `if else` statements being that I assigned the variables wrong or something.

```
// Obtain total milliseconds since midnight, Jan 1, 1970
long totalMilliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis(); 

// Seconds
long totalSeconds = totalMilliseconds / 1000;  
long currentSecond = totalSeconds % 60;

// Minutes
long totalMinutes = totalSeconds / 60;
long currentMinute = totalMinutes % 60;

// Hours
long totalHours = totalMinutes / 60;
long currentHour = totalHours % 24; 

// Read in EST offset
long offSetAdded = currentHour - 5;

// If the time is negative make it a positive
if (offSetAdded > 0) {
 long currentHourEST = offSetAdded * -1;
} else {
 long currentHourEST = offSetAdded;
}

// Display time
System.out.println("The current time is " + currentHourEST + ":" + currentMinute + ":" + currentSecond);

System.out.println("Current time in GMT is " + currentHour + ":" + currentMinute + ":" + currentSecond);
```

I am using the if else statement to multiple the `offSetAdded` by `-1` so that the hour, if it is negative when I subtract `5` from it, it becomes positive making it easier for people to see the hour. If the `offSetAdded` is positive, then it will print the `currentHour` just subtracted by 5.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The variable that is defined within `if` block is limited to that `if block` you simply cannot use the variable outside the if block.

If you want a variable to be used outside if block, just declare it outside if block.

```
// If the time is negative make it a positive
long currentHourEST;
if (offSetAdded > 0) {
 currentHourEST = offSetAdded * -1;
} else {
 currentHourEST = offSetAdded;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Change your code to:

```
// If the time is negative make it a positive
long currentHourEST;
if (offSetAdded > 0) {
    currentHourEST = offSetAdded * -1;
} else {
    currentHourEST = offSetAdded;
}
```

This will declare the variable `currentHourEST` outsite of the `if/else` block, so you can use it in the remaining code of the method.

Your current code declares the variable inside that block, that means its lifetime ends if the program exists the `if/else` block. Therefore you couldn't access it later.

Read this [tutorial about *variable scopes*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html) to learn more about that.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not an expert enough to say what's going on but, if you declare currentHourEST outside of the if statement and if else statement, it should work.
Like this:

```
long currentHourEST;

// If the time is negative make it a positive
    if (offSetAdded > 0) {
         currentHourEST = offSetAdded * -1;
    } else {
        currentHourEST = offSetAdded;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you *declare* the variable and then *initialize* it like

```
long currentHourEST;
if (offSetAdded > 0) {
  currentHourEST = offSetAdded * -1;
} else {
  currentHourEST = offSetAdded;
}
```

or you might use the conditional `? :` operator (aka a ternary)

```
long currentHourEST = (offSetAdded > 0) ? offSetAdded * -1 : offSetAdded;
```